# Rails 3 validation: two available checkboxes, can't check them both

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a very simple object that needed an approved checkbox and a Declined checkbox

How can I check to make sure that both aren't checked?

A user should only check one, not both.

Comment: That logic sounds much more appropriate to use a radio group.

Comment: Christopher: I'd say that's more like an answer than a comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Christopher Marshall pointed out - this functionality is accomplished by the `radio` button type. Just change `type="checkbox"` to `type="radio"` and make sure the `name` is the same

Comment: So what I hear you saying is: instead of having separate attributes: approve, decline, use a radio group for approve.  one would be set to true and one set to false.

Comment: @TJSherrill - Yes, that is exactly what you should do. "Approved: (o) Yes, ( ) No"